# How to make the API calls on openstack from my spring boot Applications

Tags: spring-boot, rest, integration, openstack

I want to make the API calls to OpenStack with my Spring boot Application. I am new to this please help. I am not getting the actual implementation of this process from the start. Please let me know the detailed explanation that what class and methods will be used to make the API call and how.

With my research I have the found OpenStack4j library for integration but I am not getting the proper flow.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template  You need to use RestTemplate to make REST API calls towards your OpenStack API.

Comment: How... suppose i need to create a image in  OpenStack then how can I do that

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you are trying to do here?  Do you not have an OpenStack already running?  Do you have a Springboot App already running?

Where is your springboot App running in?

Comment: Spring boot is running on my local Machine and I want to make the API call to create the  Image in OpenStack..(Yes open stack is running) i can access the dashboard of OpenStack and create the image from there but I need to do it from my spring boot application... I hope you got my point ...i am new to OpenStack so I don't know much about it

Comment: https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/image/v2/index.html?expanded=create-image-detail#create-image  Please read the documentation.

In this case, it will be a POST API call.  Use your springboot rest template, and then send a POST call like this:

`yourOpenStackURL/v2/images` and pass a JSON payload with the details you want.